# Saving and Loading Files on Emulator

Tags: android, file

I want to save a file with a string out of a edittext in it and then load it.

Somehow this doesnt work. I think the stored file can't be found or is not stored (according to logs).

How to fix this?

Here is the save code:

```
Log.i("Watcher","Saving...");
ProgressDialog dSave = ProgressDialog.show(this, "Saving", "SAving. Please wait...",false);             
String fName = "WatchConf";
EditText servPath = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.ServerPath);
String sServPath = servPath.getText().toString();

try {
    FileOutputStream fos = openFileOutput(fName, Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
        fos.write(sServPath.getBytes());
        fos.flush();
        fos.close();
        Log.d("Watcher","Saved");

        File fCheck = new File(getFilesDir()+fName);
        if(fCheck.exists()){
            Log.i("Watcher","Saved successfully");
        }
```

Code for Loading:

```
Log.i("Watcher","Loading...");
        String fName = "WatchConf";
        EditText servPath = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.ServerPath);

        try {           
            InputStreamReader isr = new InputStreamReader(openFileInput(getFilesDir()+"/"+fName));
            char[] cRead = new char[100];
            isr.read(cRead);
            String sRead = new String(cRead);
            servPath.setText(sRead);
            isr.close();
            Log.i("Watcher","Loaded");
```

Comment: try printing out sServPath in a log statement to make sure you are pulling the text you need - you may have an invalid view or something.

Comment: the view is fine, prints out the correct text

Comment: Ok I forgot the "/" between path and fName for the fCheck File. Still it the file doesnt load with the code I added above (NPE)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you written:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
```

Comment: I'm not writing external storage, am I? The Context mode is private, but I will try it now

Answer (score 0):

The reason why it was not working was, that I wanted to load the string too soon into a view.

Loading it after `setContentView(R.layout.main);` solved the problem.